# Pandas - Create a Categorical object with categories of the same priority

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have certain categories that I would like to order. For instance, colors:

```
Green = Yellow > Red
```

Here, Green and Yellow colors have the same priority, which is greater than priority of Red color. Is there a possibility to create a Categorical object like this? Can I do something like this?

```
df['Color'] = pd.Categorical(df['Color'], categories=[('Green', 'Yellow'), 'Red'], ordered=True)
```

The tuple `('Green', 'Yellow')` indicating that Green and Yellow colors are of the same priority.

Example input DataFrame:

```
ID    Color
1     Red
2     Yellow
1     Yellow
3     Red
1     Green
2     Red
```

Expected output is the DataFrame without the duplicated IDs, taking the priority of the colors into account:

```
ID    Color
1     Yellow
2     Yellow
3     Red
```

Comment: use the map version of the previous question and assign both green and yellow same value(what i can think of)

Comment: @anky_91 doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide a sample input df column and an expected df column

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I've edited the question

Comment: Check my answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved as below:

We will be considering Yellow and Green as same priority, because of the information provided.

We would be using the following methods here.

**DataFrame.apply** which allows us to apply a function along the axis  Docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

**sorted** which allows us to sort the list in the order we want by specifying the key. Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted
You can also do the same thing with list.sort but sorted gives the new object of the list.

```
import pandas as pd
#create DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,1,3,1,2],'Color':['Red','Yellow','Yellow','Red','Green','Red']})

"""
Creating a set_priority list by putting the colors with the highest priority at 
the top and the lowest priority or no priority at the bottom. This list would be 
used as the key in the sorted function below.

Below I am grouping the df with the Id and making a list of all the colors attached to the same ID. Then I am sorting the list based on the priority and choosing the first element from that list as it was asked in the question
"""

set_priority=['Yellow','Green' ,'Red']
result=df.groupby('ID')['Color'].apply(lambda x: sorted(list(x), key=lambda y: set_priority.index(y))[0]).reset_index()
```

**Result**

```
   ID   Color
0   1  Yellow
1   2  Yellow
2   3     Red
```

Comment: This solution seems to be working, but could you explain in details what exactly this snippet of code does? Because whenever I have a larger data set, and some other colors, I get a `ValueError: Purple is not in list` when the line of code with `result` is called. (I also have some other colors besides those three in my data). So I can't figure out what the problem is

Comment: @HidayetRzayev you have to add all the colors in the list "set_priority" in the priority you want. For example in the information you said, Green = Yellow > Red, which I translated to [Green,Yellow, Red]. Now if you have purple too and then it's priority is like Green = Yellow > Purple > Red, then the updated "set_priority" would be [Green, Yellow, Purple, Red]. Hope this helps, if not please let me know!

Comment: the thing is, those other colors don't have any priorities. In my case I only consider Green, Yellow and Red colors, and ignore all the other ones

Comment: Ok then if an ID only contains a color with a non-priority then you would ignore that color or how would you take care of that. Can you edit the question based on that. One solution I can think of right now is put everything else after 'Red'.

Comment: @HidayetRzayev I explained above!

Answer (score 0):

When using a categorical, a custom sort order can be specified.  This doesn't give the relation desired in the question, but maybe the `sort_dict` can be used to model such a thing.

```
import pandas as pd

colors = ["Green", "Red", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Green"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Color":colors})
sort_dict = {"Yellow":-1, "Green":1, "Red":6}
df["colorcat"] = pd.Categorical(df['Color'], categories=sorted(sort_dict, key=sort_dict.get), ordered=True)
print(df.sort_values("colorcat"))
```

```
    Color colorcat
2  Yellow   Yellow
3  Yellow   Yellow
0   Green    Green
5   Green    Green
1     Red      Red
4     Red      Red
```

Placing a tuple in the categories does not appear to work.

```
import pandas as pd

colors = ["Green", "Red", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Red", "Green"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Color":colors})
df["colorcat"] = pd.Categorical(df['Color'], categories=[("Green", "Yellow"), "Red"], ordered=True)
print(df.sort_values("colorcat"))
```

```
    Color colorcat
1     Red      Red
4     Red      Red
0   Green      NaN
2  Yellow      NaN
3  Yellow      NaN
5   Green      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
# Create an example dataframe
data = {'ID': ['1' , '2', '1', '3', '1', '2'], 
        'Color': ['Red' , 'Yellow' , 'Yellow' , 'Red', 'Green', 'Red']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

a = df1.join(df1.groupby(['ID'])['Color'].apply(set).rename('m'),
             on=['ID'])['m']

m1 = (a == set({'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red'})) | (a == set({'Green', 'Yellow'}))| (a == set({'Red', 'Yellow'}))
m2 = a == set({'Red'})

m4 = df1['Color'] == 'Yellow'
m5 = df1['Color'] == 'Red'

df1 = df1[(m1 & m4) | (m2 & m5) ]
```

print(df1)

```
    Color ID
1  Yellow  2
2  Yellow  1
3     Red  3
```

Comment: @hidayetRzayev: Have you tried my solution..tell me if it is not working ?

Comment: unfortunately no, it removes more rows than it should in a larger data set

Comment: Don't understand how.. Replicate the same varibality which you have in original df, I can modify accordingly

Comment: Kartikeya Sharma's answer works for this particular problem